# Eliminate the confirmation alert from the javaScript code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                        <div>
                           <input type="number" id="items_percentage" value="<?php echo $task->task_item_percentage; ?>" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter Percentage value" style="width: 160px;text-align: center;">
                           <div><small><b>(Please Enter Value Without Percentage %)</b></small></div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                           <h3>Or</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                           <input type="number" id="task_item_manual_total_price" value="<?php echo $task->task_item_manual_total_price; ?>" placeholder="Enter Total Price" style="width: 160px;text-align: center;">
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
                           <a href="javascript:;" id="saveItemsPercentageBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Save</a>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        
                  </div>
```

And the javaScript code:

```
 $(document).on("click","#saveItemsPercentageBtn", function(){
            var didConfirm = confirm("Do you want to save total percentage price ? ");
            if (didConfirm === true) {
               var taskid = '<?php echo $task->id; ?>';
               var task_item_percentage = $("#items_percentage").val();
               var task_item_manual_total_price = $("#task_item_manual_total_price").val();

               if(taskid && task_item_percentage && task_item_percentage != ""){
                  $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: admin_url+"tasks/update_task_item_percentage",
                       data: {id:taskid,task_item_percentage:task_item_percentage},
                       success: function(data) {
                           alert("Successfully updated percentag price...!");
                           window.location.reload();
                       }
                  });
               }

               if(taskid && task_item_manual_total_price && task_item_manual_total_price != ""){
                  $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: admin_url+"tasks/update_task_item_manual_total_price",
                       data: {id:taskid,task_item_manual_total_price:task_item_manual_total_price},
                       success: function(data) {
                           alert("Successfully updated total price...!");
                           window.location.reload();
                       }
                  });
               }
            }
            //$(document).off("ajaxSuccess")
         });
```

My question is how can I eliminate the confirmation messages? I want my inputs to be save without reloading and without confirming!
Can someone help me please? If you will need more details i will tell you all you need! Thanks

Comment: Remove the `confirm()` call...? Also, if you remove the refresh you'll need to manually update the DOM of the current page with the new data.

Comment: Change `alert("...` to... well.. nothing, just remove the line (or if you prefer change to  `//alert("`).  Same for `window.location.reload`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For removes confirmation messages

```
var didConfirm = confirm("Do you want to save total percentage price ? ");
        if (didConfirm === true) {
```

and the last close bracket of if conditional ' } '

Success is getting the response of the request if you remove that, the alert and reload will dissapear

```
success: function(data) {
                       alert("Successfully updated percentag price...!");
                       window.location.reload();
                   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did as you said, and it works and saves only the first input the 2nd input is not saveing anymore